# JavaScript for opening a specific URL when I click on any hyperlink

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, blogger

Here is my present code,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(){
    var els = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (i=0;i<els.length;i++) {
        els[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
            window.open('http://www.example.com');
        });
    }
})();
</script>
```

It does what I needed but the problem is it opens a new tab every time when I click on any hyperlink within my Blogger blog. Is it possible to open only one new tab though the user clicks on several hyperlinks until the next visit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add same "target" attribute to all of your links, this way they will all be opened in same new tab.

```
 <a target="mywindow" href="http://www.example.com">link</a>
```

Also, you can use second parameter of the window.open method, and pass same window name there

```
window.open("http://www.example.com", "mywindow");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should get by id and you should give a specific id to hyperlink which you want to use

Comment: That is not possible. There are thousands of hyperlinks within my blog. I need to target them directly instead giving them an unique ID (perhaps thousands of IDs)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
window.location = 'http://www.example.com'
```

instead of

```
window.open('http://www.example.com');
```